# How does Spring Batch CompositeItemWriter manage transaction for delegate writers?

Tags: spring, spring-batch, compositeitemwriter

In the batch job step configuration, I plan to execute 2 queries in the writer, the 1st query is to update records in table A, then the 2nd query is to insert new records in table A again.

So far I think CompositeItemWriter can achieve my goal above, i.e., I need to create 2 JdbcBatchItemWriters, one is for update, and the other one is for insert.

My first question is if CompositeItemWriter is a fit for the requirement above?

If yes, that lead to the second question about transaction. For example, if the first update is successful, and the second insert fails. Will the 1st update transaction be rolled back automatically? Otherwise, how to manually pull both updates in the same transaction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As I understand it, the Spring Batch framework manages transaction for you: the reader/processor/writer steps are always within a transaction, and configuration parameters control how many items the framework ill make part of the same transaction, before it commits and starts a new transaction to continue work in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> My first question is if CompositeItemWriter is a fit for the requirement above?

Yes, `CompositeItemWriter` is the way to go.

> If yes, that lead to the second question about transaction. For example, if the first update is successful, and the second insert fails. Will the 1st update transaction be rolled back automatically? Otherwise, how to manually pull both updates in the same transaction?

Excellent question! Yes, if the update succeeds in the first writer and then the insert fails in the second writer, all statements will be rolled back automatically. What you need to know is that the transaction is around the execution of the chunk oriented tasklet step (and so around the `write` method of the composite item writer). Hence, the execution of all sql statements within this method (executed in delegate writers) will be atomic.

To illustrate this use case, I wrote the following test:

- Given a table `people` with two columns `id` and `name` with only one record inside it: `1,'foo'`
- Let's imagine a job that reads two records (`1,'foo'`, `2,'bar'`) and tries to update `foo` to `foo!!` and then inserts `2,'bar'` in the table. This is done with a `CompositeItemWriter` with two item writers: `UpdateItemWriter` and `InsertItemWriter`
- The use case is that `UpdateItemWriter` succeeds but `InsertItemWriter` fails (by throwing an exception)
- The expected result is that `foo` is not updated to `foo!!` and `bar` is not inserted in the table (Both sql statements are rolled back due to the exception in the `InsertItemWriter`)

Here is the code (it is self-contained so you can try it and see how things work, it uses an embedded hsqldb database which should be in your classpath):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import org.springframework.batch.core.ExitStatus;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.test.JobLauncherTestUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.jdbc.JdbcTestUtils;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TransactionWithCompositeWriterTest.JobConfiguration.class)
public class TransactionWithCompositeWriterTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        jdbcTemplate.update("CREATE TABLE people (id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(20));");
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO people (id, name) VALUES (1, 'foo');");
    }

    @Test
    public void testTransactionRollbackWithCompositeWriter() throws Exception {
        // given
        int peopleCount = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "people");
        int fooCount = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTableWhere(jdbcTemplate, "people", "id = 1 and name = 'foo'");
        int barCount = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTableWhere(jdbcTemplate, "people", "id = 2 and name = 'bar'");
        Assert.assertEquals(1, peopleCount);
        Assert.assertEquals(1, fooCount);
        Assert.assertEquals(0, barCount);

        // when
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncherTestUtils.launchJob();

        // then
        Assert.assertEquals(ExitStatus.FAILED.getExitCode(), jobExecution.getExitStatus().getExitCode());
        Assert.assertEquals("Something went wrong!", jobExecution.getAllFailureExceptions().get(0).getMessage());
        StepExecution stepExecution = jobExecution.getStepExecutions().iterator().next();
        Assert.assertEquals(0, stepExecution.getCommitCount());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, stepExecution.getRollbackCount());
        Assert.assertEquals(0, stepExecution.getWriteCount());

        peopleCount = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "people");
        fooCount = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTableWhere(jdbcTemplate, "people", "id = 1 and name = 'foo'");
        barCount = JdbcTestUtils.countRowsInTableWhere(jdbcTemplate, "people", "id = 2 and name = 'bar'");
        Assert.assertEquals(1, peopleCount); // bar is not inserted
        Assert.assertEquals(0, barCount); // bar is not inserted
        Assert.assertEquals(1, fooCount); // foo is not updated to "foo!!"
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    public static class JobConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public DataSource dataSource() {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                    .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                    .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-drop-hsqldb.sql")
                    .addScript("/org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql")
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Bean
        public ItemReader<Person> itemReader() {
            Person foo = new Person(1, "foo");
            Person bar = new Person(2, "bar");
            return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(foo, bar));
        }

        @Bean
        public ItemWriter<Person> updateItemWriter() {
            return new UpdateItemWriter(dataSource());
        }

        @Bean
        public ItemWriter<Person> insertItemWriter() {
            return new InsertItemWriter(dataSource());
        }

        @Bean
        public ItemWriter<Person> itemWriter() {
            CompositeItemWriter<Person> compositeItemWriter = new CompositeItemWriter<>();
            compositeItemWriter.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(updateItemWriter(), insertItemWriter()));
            return compositeItemWriter;
        }

        @Bean
        public Job job(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory) {
            return jobBuilderFactory.get("job")
                    .start(stepBuilderFactory
                            .get("step").<Person, Person>chunk(2)
                            .reader(itemReader())
                            .writer(itemWriter())
                            .build())
                    .build();
        }

        @Bean
        public JobLauncherTestUtils jobLauncherTestUtils() {
            return new JobLauncherTestUtils();
        }
    }

    public static class UpdateItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Person> {

        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public UpdateItemWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(List<? extends Person> items) {
            for (Person person : items) {
                if ("foo".equalsIgnoreCase(person.getName())) {
                    jdbcTemplate.update("UPDATE people SET name = 'foo!!' WHERE id = 1");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class InsertItemWriter implements ItemWriter<Person> {

        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

        public InsertItemWriter(DataSource dataSource) {
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(List<? extends Person> items) {
            for (Person person : items) {
                if ("bar".equalsIgnoreCase(person.getName())) {
                    jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO people (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)", person.getId(), person.getName());
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Something went wrong!");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static class Person {

        private long id;

        private String name;

        public Person() {
        }

        public Person(long id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        public long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

My example uses custom item writers but this should work with two `JdbcBatchItemWriter`s as well.

I hope this helps!

Comment: I have tried your example. UpdateItemWriter succeeds and InsertItemWriter fail. However, the value in 1st statement is still updated. Are there any thing wrong? Im using Spring Batch 4.2.1 and Oracle as Datasource. 1 more question is that could my job do Insert even when my 1st Update is fail? and how? @Mahmoud Ben Hassine

Comment: Just tested with oracle DB, the same test passes. `1 more question is that could my job do Insert even when my 1st Update is fail?` No, that's the idea, the transaction is around the composite writer: so no matter which delegate fails, the transaction will be rolled back for all delegates. It is all or nothing.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine - Is there any way if we can somehow allow the 1st Transaction to be get successful even though 2nd Writer Update failed ? If 2nd writer updates failed then we should save the correct data and save the junk data into the error table ?