# Spring Batch Composite Item Writer Transaction Management

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, transactionmanager

Regarding the post [How does Spring Batch CompositeItemWriter manage transaction for delegate writers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51904498/how-does-spring-batch-compositeitemwriter-manage-transaction-for-delegate-writer) , for composite item writer transaction management, shouldn't we wrap the data source in a transaction manager like below ? Without the below bean definition the transaction management is not working with Oracle and Hikari CP. Not sure how the provided example in the post is working..please clarify

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(DataSource dataSource) {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(dataSource);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add that bean, the example provides a `DataSource` and uses `@EnableBatchProcessing`, so Spring Batch will configure a `DataSourceTransactionManager` by default. This is explained in the documentation of [@EnableBatchProcessing](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/configuration/annotation/EnableBatchProcessing.html).

Comment: I am setting the spring batch datasource as null by extending DefaultBatchConfigurer because I dont need that feature..

```
@Override
    public void setDataSource(final DataSource dataSource) {
        // initialize with NULL to do in-memory job initialization
        super.setDataSource(null);
    }
```

Could that be the reason it is not working for my application datasource without the  Datasource transaction manager definition? it only works when I I add the Datasource transaction manager  bean explicitly

Comment: do you think it is causing the issue ?

Comment: No, in this case, you need to define the transaction manager yourself and set it on the step.